# Import deployed 2012 into VS 2017 while keeping target 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have a SSIS project that is deployed on SQL 2012.  Since 2012 is EOL, I need to convert to 2019.  However, the previous owner used a 3rd party task that does not seem to work in the newer version of VS.  When I try to import the project, it sets the default target to 2019.  Even if I change that to 2012 and let it convert, it still has errors and restarts VS when I try to open this task (I have installed the task on my machine).  And when I create a 2012 targeted project, it allows me to open the task.

The task does not even show in 2019.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to start a new project.  Convert it to target 2012, then then import the existing package.

Every attempt I have made causes it to fail.

I did install VS 2012 and that seemed to work, but then I got a message from our IT group that VS 2012 is to be uninstalled and the project did not seem to open in VS 2017 properly either.

If I do the conversion to 2012, it gives errors, will not allow me to open it, but it does show the task as visible, so I think it is the conversion that is the problem.

I do not even need this to work as is, just need it to know what they have done so it can be converted.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Both VS2017 and VS2019.
Save the studio when importing target server SQL Server 2012, but there is a version mismatch in the package code that prevents conversion. In particular, the script components.

```
     <Compile Include="ComponentWrapper.cs" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91">
      <Private>False</Private>
```

Must be Version=11.0.0.0

```
<HostIdentifier>SSIS_SC150</HostIdentifier>
```

Must be
`<HostIdentifier>SSIS_SC110</HostIdentifier>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and used this workaround:

Export the SSIS project, from the Integration Services Catalogs - SSISDB, into the default .ispac.
Rename the .ispac by just adding .zip to the end. It's now a compressed file.
Export the .zip into a folder.
Start up Visual Studio, and create a new SSIS Project with whatever target version you need.
Import the SSIS package that you originally got from the .ispac.